# Read Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am writing some code to read an excel file, but unfortuantely the excel file contains more than 300 columns and I need to read all 300.

I've been using some 3rd Part libraries to do this [LinqToExcel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) but they can only read a **maximum of 256 columns**

```
        var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(FileName);

        var recs = (from ws in excel.Worksheet<Sample>("data export final")
                    select ws).ToList()
```

Does anyone know how I can read all 300 columns, preferabbly without having to install Microst Office as this will be running on a server which doesn't have that installed

Comment: You could try Koogra - http://sourceforge.net/projects/koogra - as it works with Excel 2007 files (when the 256 column limit was lifted..)

Comment: If you're willing to look beyond .Net, then both Perl and Python have open source modules available for working with spreadsheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/downloads/get/329346) can read and write > 256 columns.  Here's a short example showing writing to column 300.

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\sample300.xlsx");
if (newFile.Exists)
{
    newFile.Delete();  // ensures we create a new workbook
    newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\sample300.xlsx");
}

using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    // add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Inventory");
    //Add the headers
    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 300].Value = "Col 300";
    package.Save();
}
```

Reading from column 300+ is just as easy, but it's harder to post a self-contained example that includes a large input file :-)

Comment: @ChrisK: No, only .xlsx files.  The (open source) developers take the position that they should not invest their unpaid time developing for an old technology :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are several options - all involve some additional library:

OpenXML 2.0 (free library from MS) can be used to read/modify the content of an .xlsx so you can do with it what you want

some (commercial) 3rd-party libraries come with grid controls allowing you to do much more with excel files in your application (be it Winforms/WPF/ASP.NET...) like SpreadsheetGear, Aspose.Cells etc.

Comment: I would either use Aspose or Open XML

Comment: Aspose is not free.  Open XML is harder to use imho than EPPlus.

Comment: yea EPPlus is better but i am telling what i used in order to be able to help with it..

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code based on OleDbDataAdapter

```
            string filename = @"....xls";
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                                          "Data Source=" + filename + ";" +
                                          "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Sample");
            DataTable dataTable = myDataSet.Tables["Sample"];


            var rows = from p in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                       select new 
                       {
                           Property = p.Field<string>("Column")
                       };
```